# PHP - Check if string contains illegal chars in string

Tags: php, string

In JS you can do:

```
 var chs = "[](){}";
 var str = "hello[asd]}";
 if (str.indexOf(chs) != -1) {
    alert("The string can't contain the following characters: " + chs.split("").join(", "));
 }
```

How can you do this in PHP (replacing alert with echo)?

I do not want to use a regex for the simplicity of what I think.

EDIT:

What I've tried:

```
 <?php
    $chs = /[\[\]\(\)\{\}]/;
    $str = "hella[asd]}";
    if (preg_match(chs, str)) {
       echo ("The string can't contain the following characters: " . $chs);
    }
 ?>
```

Which obviously doesn't work and idk how to do it without regex.

Comment: Please explain downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but the reason might be you haven't shown what you've tried yourself to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, looks much better. Remember to show what you've attempted yourself in a question. It shows you made the effort and also gives us a basic starting point.

Comment: @artm Thought it would be obvious with so little code, and I start at the wrong beginning, with regexes.

Comment: It might me obvious to you but not to us. And when you don't post what you've tried it somewhat gives the feeling that you came here with the first problem you had, without trying anything yourself. People here aren't too keen to fix problems for others but need to see an attempt made.

Comment: `preg_match($chs, $str)` ... chs, str not defined as consts

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In php you should do this:

```
$string = "Sometring[inside]";

if(preg_match("/(?:\[|\]|\(|\)|\{|\})+/", $string) === FALSE)
{
     echo "it does not contain.";
}
else
{
     echo "it contains";
}
```

The regex says check to see any of the characters are inside the string. you can read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

And about PHP preg_match() :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

**Update:**

I have written an updated regex for this, which captures the letters inside:

```
$rule = "/(?:(?:\[([\s\da-zA-Z]+)\])|\{([\d\sa-zA-Z]+)\})|\(([\d\sa-zA-Z]+)\)+/"
$matches = array();
if(preg_match($rule, $string, $matches) === true)
{
   echo "It contains: " . $matches[0];
}
```

It returnes something like this:

```
It contains: [inside]
```

I have changed the regex only which becomes:

```
$rule = "/(?:(?:(\[)(?:[\s\da-zA-Z]+)(\]))|(\{)(?:[\d\sa-zA-Z]+)(\}))|(\()(?:[\d\sa-zA-Z]+)(\))+/";
```

// it returns an array of occurred illegal characters

It now returns `[]` for this `"I am [good]"`

Comment: But I want to do: echo "It contains" . chars, which doesn't work with a regex and I clearly said that I did not want to use a regex.

Comment: I want an exact translation.

Comment: I have updated the question, and it does what you want @Murplyx

Answer (score 0):

Why not you try str_replace.

```
<?php    

$search  = array('[',']','{','}','(',')');
    $replace = array('');
    $content = 'hella[asd]}';
    echo str_replace($search, $replace, $content);
 //Output => hellaasd

?>
```

Instead of regex we can use string replace for this case.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution without using regex:

```
$chs = array("[", "]", "(", ")", "{", "}");
$string = "hello[asd]}";
$err = array();

foreach($chs AS $key => $val)
{
    if(strpos($string, $val) !== false) $err[]= $val; 
}

if(count($err) > 0)
{
    echo "The string can't contain the following characters: " . implode(", ", $err);
}
```